# c# uwp textblock text property not updating UI during runtime

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, uwp, sum

I'm selecting an item from a combobox to filter a listview of items. The items contain values, and are displayed in a View depending on the filter selection.

```
<ComboBox  Name="YearComboBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind StudentEnrollment.Years, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValue="{x:Bind StudentEnrollment.SelectedYear, Mode=TwoWay}”/>

<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind StudentEnrollment.FilteredStudentEnrollments, Mode=OneWay}"  SelectedIndex="{x:Bind StudentEnrollment.SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:StudentViewModel" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Score01, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

public class StudentEnrollmentViewModel : NotificationBase
{
    StudentEnrollment StudentEnrollment;

    public StudentEnrollmentViewModel()
    {

    }

    private ObservableCollection<StudentEnrollmentViewModel> _StudentEnrollments;
    public ObservableCollection<StudentEnrollmentViewModel> StudentEnrollments
   {
        get { return _StudentEnrollments; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _StudentEnrollments, value);
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<StudentEnrollmentViewModel> _FilteredStudentEnrollments;
    public ObservableCollection<StudentEnrollmentViewModel> FilteredStudentEnrollments
    {
        get { return _FilteredStudentEnrollments; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _FilteredStudentEnrollments, value);
        }
    }

    private string _selectedYear;
    public string SelectedYear
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedYear;
        }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedYear, value);
            { RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedYear); }
            RefreshFilteredStudentEnrollmentData(); }
    }

    private double _Score01;
    public double Score01
    {
        get
        {
            _Score01 = FilteredStudentEnrollments.Where(y => y.Year == SelectedYear).Select(s => s.Score01).Sum();
            return _Score01;
        }
    }

    private void RefreshFilteredStudentEnrollmentData()
    {
        var se = from seobjs in StudentEnrollments
                  where seobjs.Year == SelectedYear
                  select seobjs;

       if (FilteredStudentEnrollments.Count == se.Count()) || FilteredStudentEnrollments == null
       return;

        FilteredStudentEnrollments = new ObservableCollection<StudentEnrollmentViewModel>(se);
    }
```

As expected I can sum the filtered values, and display the total in a TextBlock text property per listview column when the page loads.

```
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind StudentEnrollment.Score01, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The issue's the Textblock UI does not update/display the changing property value in the viewmodel via a combobox selection. I sure I'm missing something, or have some logic backwards, hoping some fresh eyes can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which class is which, because there seems to be some mix up between `StudentEnrollmentViewModel` and `StudentViewModel`, but I think I see the reason for the problem.

The `Score01` property is a get-only property (actually you can get rid of the `_Score01` field and just return the value). Its value is dependent on the `FilteredStudentEnrollments` and `SelectedYear` properties. But the UI does not know that so you have to notify it when these properties change that it should bind a new value of `Score01` as well:

```
private ObservableCollection<StudentEnrollmentViewModel> _FilteredStudentEnrollments;
public ObservableCollection<StudentEnrollmentViewModel> FilteredStudentEnrollments
{
    get { return _FilteredStudentEnrollments; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _FilteredStudentEnrollments, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Score01");
    }
}

private string _selectedYear;
public string SelectedYear
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedYear;
    }
    set 
    { 
       SetProperty(ref _selectedYear, value);
       RaisePropertyChanged("Score01");
       RefreshFilteredStudentEnrollmentData();
    }
}

public double Score01
{
    get
    {
        return FilteredStudentEnrollments.
            Where(y => y.Year == SelectedYear).Select(s => s.Score01).Sum();            
    }
}
```

Notice I have changed the `RaisePropertyChanged` call to pass in `"Score01"`, as the method expects the name of the property, whereas you were previously passing the value of the `SelectedYear` property, which meant the `PropertyChanged` event executed for something like `2018` instead of the property itself. Also note that `SetProperty` method internally calls `RaisePropertyChanged` for `SelectedYear` property as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance and clarification. That solved the issue and my binding is now updating as expected.

Comment: Glad to help! If it solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as the solution so that the question is resolved :-)